# specifying labels using cut() on raster

Tags: r, raster

Suppose I have a the following raster:

```
library(raster)    
r <- raster(ncols=36, nrows=18)
values(r) <- rnorm(ncell(r))
```

I can discretise its values using `cut()`:

```
breaks <- -2:2 * 3
rc <- cut(r, breaks=breaks)
```

However, when i try to specify labels e.g., A, B, C, etc

```
rc <- cut(r, breaks=breaks, labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
```

it returns the following error.

```
Error in cut.default(getValues(x), breaks = breaks, labels = FALSE,
...) :    formal argument "labels" matched by multiple actual
arguments
```

I tried googling the error message but no luck. Any ideas what is going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you only have 5 breaks, so you can only have 4 labels. Secondly, you could use `cut` on the data of the raster rather than the whole raster object:

```r
rc <- r
rc[] <- cut(rc[], breaks = breaks, labels = c("A", "B","C","D"))
rc
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> dimensions : 18, 36, 648  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 10, 10  (x, y)
#> extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 
#> source     : memory
#> names      : layer 
#> values     : 1, 4  (min, max)
#> attributes :
#>  ID VALUE
#>   1     A
#>   2     B
#>   3     C
#>   4     D
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do that, using `terra`:

```
library(terra)    
r <- rast(ncols=36, nrows=18)
values(r) <- rnorm(ncell(r)) 
breaks <- -2:2 * 3

rc <- classify(r, breaks)
levels(rc)[[1]]
#  ID   lyr.1
#1  0 (-6–-3]
#2  1  (-3–0]
#3  2   (0–3]
#4  3   (3–6]

levels(rc) <- data.frame(ID=0:3, label=c("A", "B", "C", "D"))

rc
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 18, 36, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#categories  : label 
#name        : label 
#min value   :     A 
#max value   :     D
```